# Struts2 export as excel with larger data 12000 rows

Tags: java, excel, struts2, apache-poi

```
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet(sheetName);
            XSSFCellStyle style = book.createCellStyle();
            XSSFFont font = book.createFont();
            font.setBold(true);
            style.setFont(font);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                Map map = tempList.get(0);
                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < map.size(); j++) {

                    // Element cell = tr.select("td").get(j);
                    XSSFCell name = row.createCell((short) j);
                    name.setCellValue(String.valueOf(map.get(displayName[j])));

                    if (i == 0) {
                        name.setCellStyle(style);
                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(j);
                    }
                }
            }

            String fileName = "Extract Contacts";

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            book.write(baos);
            byte[] xls = baos.toByteArray();
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            baos.writeTo(outputStream);
            response.setContentLength(xls.length);
            response.setHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"Extract_Contacts.xlsx\"");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

the above code works with minimal rows says around 100. when row exceeds 10000 record. the file name and content type are not set. file name shows as generateExcel.action(ie actionName).
Thank you

Comment: Use SXSSFWorkbook class instead. It uses a lot less memory. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html

Comment: Should you not **first** set response content length, content type and header and **then** write to the response output-stream?